# What's the pixel for per StrokeThickness in WVGA(480*800) in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

Does anyone know that what's the pixel for StrokeThickness=1 in windows phone WVGA device.

I'd like to design a 4 pixel StrokeThikcness for a rectangle.

But I don't know what value should StrokeThickness be set for rectangle to meet 4 pixel border(stroke).

Comment: Isn't `4` what you want?

Comment: I can't be sure if it's correct. I happened have no tool to verify it

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't be correct? It's a Device Independent Pixel.

Comment: What confusing me is that I can't tell what StrokeThikcness is based on. Pixel? inch?

And does it react the same on WVGA and 720p device.

Comment: As I said, it's a device independent pixel. There's a lot of good documentation about them on MSDN.